# How to clear css cache

Tags: php, css

I am building my [blog](http://www.bgmemo.com) by PHP and Godaddy apache server, recently I face a problem that I cannot clear the explorer cache so that each time when I change my style.css I have to change the name of the css file. So can you tell what is wrong or how can I clear the css cache?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force browser to use new CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101125/force-browser-to-use-new-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the Browsing History cache in your Browser...
This is not related to PHP..

Comment: actually you could use php to append a timestamp to your CSS reference.

Comment: well clearing his browser history doesnt clears his users' browsing history

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I mean the whole functionality and how the browser treats a CSS file is not related to PHP.

Comment: Thank you Mina, it works for me. It is really not related to PHP. I have thought it is the problem of setting css expiredate in htaccess, but it is the problem of my brwsing history.

Comment: Please share more details. How would this work for other visitors of a website? Should the OP add a warning to their site, that the cache should be cleared on each request?

Answer (score 10):

You can make the browser automatically clear cache if you create a `version` based on file modified time

eg:

```
$filename = '/css/style.css';
$fileModified = substr(md5(filemtime($filename)), 0, 6);
// $fileModified = filemtime($filename); // - with version as timestamp.
```

and HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $filename;?>?v=<?php echo $fileModified ; ?>">
```

Comment: Why to `md5` if you can just use `filemtime`?

Comment: Because I believe is fancier, why everyone needs to see when you modified your files? :)

Comment: nothing wrong with having filemtime ;-) Personally I prefer not to do things, that bring no benefits. That is why I asked about why to `md5`. I've upvoted you because your answer is the most correct among others, but another unnecessary step with `md5` still confuses me

Comment: Mihai, thank you so much for your work. Here you give me a bright new idea to do something similar, but Mina's answer seems work for me, so still upvoted yours. Cheers.

Comment: @BGMEMO yes, but thing it will solve only in your browser. Others may have to wait for browser to clear cache.

Comment: Of cause, just for testing purpose. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Put Version Number for your css file like following,

```
style.css?v=1 or style.css?v=1.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you asking for?

```
<link href="style.css?key=<?php echo time(); ?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Best is to keep it like this on your local or testing server only - remove time() part when the site goes live

UPDATE

or instead of `time()` you could use `key=<?php echo date('h'); ?>` for hourly or change as you'd like it be.

Comment: this could effect the performance of you site as the css will never be cached.

Comment: Yes of course- it is set that way above - if you don't want it be cached just remove the time() part.

Comment: @HappyApe: I just wanted to say that this is the terrible way to solve OP's problem

Comment: Where is your solution @zerkms?

Comment: @HappyApe: I'm with Mihai Iorga's one

Comment: @zerkms - its much better solution than what OP is currently doing (renaming file)

Comment: @HappyApe: but still: 1. solution with hour - will give you obsolete file for about potentially 60 minutes. 2. solution with `time()` will require each time download the file (poor users). There is a good solution, see the most upvoted answer

Comment: @zerkms Keep in mind that it's NOT your question - OP may have his/her own requirements. I'm not going to whap you with a stick if you don't like my solution.

Comment: @HappyApe: it's not about "like/not like" it's about efficiency. Your solution less efficient than the most upvoted one. It is just a fact. And it makes no sense arguing more - but your solution is just bad, because it prevents browsers of using cache.

Comment: @zerkms The question is not about efficiency.

Comment: @HappyApe: it makes sense to solve **any** issue using the best possible solution. Random filenames is just a bad way of serving **static** files.

Comment: @zerkms whatever - it's not your question - what best for you might be a terrible for other

Comment: @HappyApe: when you prevent of using caching (you know, it's a mechanism for increasing pages loading speed) - it by default is not "the best" solution. Especially when we can both solve the issue and keep caching (see the top answer) ;-) And doesn't matter who asked the question - I'm confident enough to compare the answers

Comment: @zerkms - If the OP is developing the website and making changes every few seconds he/she maynot be interested in caching at all - I know that Mihai's answer has filetime as the version number to clear the cache so does mine (to clear the cache). Once the development stage is over just change to something more suitable.

Comment: @HappyApe: or you can use consistent solution that works perfectly in every environment. How about that?

Comment: @zerkms - Just change the browser how about that?

Comment: @HappyApe: so in your projects you ask your users to change their browsers? I prefer to implement solutions that work regardless of browser used.

Comment: @zerkms - Since when I said above is my personal solution ;-) lol

Comment: @HappyApe: I never doubt that you choose something weird rather than something that work good ;-)

Comment: @zerkms ... and I literally read the question title and provided this answer in few seconds - If you were so confident why did you not provide your solution. I'm sure I'd have posted a different answer if there was efficiency in question.

Comment: @HappyApe: I didn't post mine because there was already good one. "if there was efficiency in question" --- I cannot imagine in what universe turning off caching for css is acceptable answer ;-) I wouldn't do that even if some asked me whether I choose life or uncached static resources.

Comment: @zerkms you have the right to form an opinion and freedom to choose among different option and I have the guts the provide a solution DIFFERENT than what other people are saying. I don't care if people like it or not. And I'm not going whap with a stick if you don't use mine. ;-)

Comment: @HappyApe: right ;-) That's why I don't understand why you start advocating your solution ;-)

Comment: @zerkms - it's my baby - I'm gonna take good care of it cos I am good fella ... ;-) lol

Answer (score 1):

```
<link href="style.css?t=[timestamp]" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: it will force a get of the latest file

Comment: @zerkms no it treats it as a totaly different file,

Comment: @Blowsie: I know that. But do you realize that will impact the overall page loading time? Nowadays people try to make their sites faster by using caching and reducing amount of HTTP requests

Answer (score 0):

Use a random number as a parameter with your CSS file. It is one of the easiest way to cache everytime on your browser when file get loaded.

Ex:

```
style.css?v=12345
```

Comment: Random number **each** request?

Comment: @zerkms.. yes each and every time we need the randon number for browser loading because the above requirement is for frequent changes. But we have to remove this additional parameter after certain time for improving the server performance.

Comment: well "every time we need the randon number for browser loading because the above requirement is for frequent changes" --- that's not true. There are solutions without any randomness. See the most upvoted answer

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Especially if you had to remove that parameter again: what's the alternative?

Answer (score -1):

For chrome: click on the top right menu button, click on settings, scroll down to advanced and click on it, and click on "Clear browsing data" and tick Cached images and files.

Comment: Please share more details. How would this work for other visitors of a website? Should the OP add a warning to their site, that the cache should be cleared on each request?

Answer (score -2):

Just press Ctrl+F5 in browser or another combination that update page with clearing cache.

Comment: Please share more details. How would this work for other visitors of a website? Should the OP add a warning to their site, that the cache should be cleared on each request?