# Append querystring to all HTTP Requests in IIS

Tags: css, asp.net, iis

I have an DotNetNuke (DNN) website running on IIS 7.5 that is undergoing some CSS\JS changes, and these changes are due to launch in the near future.  Like any other web dev in the world, I have concerns about the caching of local content.

I set some HTTP cache control headers in IIS to expire content immediately, but I also wanted to force new content regardless if I could.. something like what is mentioned here - [Force browser to use new CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101125/force-browser-to-use-new-css), which is to append a querystring value to all JS\CSS requests.

My problem is, because I don't have access to the source for my DNN website, I can't programmatically just append the querystring values to my CSS\JS requests.  So instead, Im hoping I can just append a dummy querystring value to all HTTP Responses, even something as simple as appending skin.css?x=1.

So my questions are, can I use something like the IIS URL Rewrite module to append querystring values to responses, or if not something else?  Can I do so only on CSS\JS, or is it an all or none scenario? And if I can do any of the above, I'd like to also respect the fact that some of my URLs on the page already have querystring values passed, so I want to avoid having multiple "?" characters in my URL.. if possible.

Comment: It is possible to use IIS URL Rewrite to _redirect_ to another URL; but I think there must be a better idea. I'll wait for few answers first.

Comment: Thanks @SalmanA, truth be told, this is just my ace up the sleeve approach, incase VP's freak out because a logo isn't positions with perfect 7px margins from the mid-left positioning of the page :)  I don't want to go this route, and if I do, it's just a temporary thing.. but it's nice to know that if needed.. I *could* force users to update CSS files this way..